# How to scale some overlay image in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

```html
ffmpeg -i tmp3.mp4 -i sucai/s4.jpg -i sucai/s1.mp4 -filter_complex "[1]scale=500:500[b];[0][b]overlay=x=0:y=0:enable='between(t,0,5)',overlay=x=0:y=0:enable='between(t,8,15)'" o.mp4 -y
```

This command can only process the first inserted picture, and will not work for the second one.
could you help me?
thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Add another [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale), use `;` instead of `,` to join non-linear sets of filters, and consider adding `shortest=1` to the last [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay):

```
ffmpeg -i tmp3.mp4 -i sucai/s4.jpg -i sucai/s1.mp4 -filter_complex "[1]scale=500:500[b];[2]scale=500:500[c];[0][b]overlay=x=0:y=0:enable='between(t,0,5)'[bg];[bg][c]overlay=x=0:y=0:enable='between(t,8,15)':shortest=1" o.mp4
```